# How to find words having same number of length in a paragraph in php?

Tags: php, string

Here is my paragraph:

```
$string = "A country is a region legally identified as a distinct entity in political geography.
```

i tried it by,

```
$word = str_word_count($string); but it returns number of words only.
```

now i want to count number of letters with having length 2. In the given string their are 3 words with having number of letters 2.

how is it possible in PHP? please help me to find out the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You could do like this

```
<?php
$string = "A country is a region legally identified as a distinct entity in political geography.";
$arr = explode(' ',$string);
foreach($arr as $val)
{
    if(strlen($val)==2)
    {
        echo "$val has a length of 2.<br>";
    }
}
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
is has a length of 2.
as has a length of 2.
in has a length of 2.
```

Comment: Thank you..it's the correct solution to my problem.